# Scrapear web que espera respuesta de API

Tags: javascript, nodejs, scraping

Quiero scarpear información de esta web: https://www.lcfc.com/matches/results, en especial los resultados de los partidos, que se encuentran dentro de estas etiquetas (que visualmente seria lo que muestra dentro de las secciones ejemplo October 2020 y los partidos jugados):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la primera vez que veo web scraping y probé hacerlo con Cheerio y con Puppeteer pero ninguna me dio resultados. Este es el JS que hago en la consola del navegador que por ejemplo me devuelve los nombres de los equipos de manera correcta:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
  .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
```

Si usan ese código en la consola, verán que obtiene los nombres de los equipos, pero ahora no se como hacer para obtenermelos dentro de mi código. Yo creo que lo que sucede es que la API se esta ejecutando y todavía no devolvió nada, por lo que esta en null lo que pido. Les muestro ejemplos que trate de hacer:

Puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch() ;
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.lcfc.com/matches/results');
    await page.waitForSelector('.match-item__team-container span');
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.match-item__team-container span')
            .forEach(element => console.log(element.textContent));
          //or return the values of the selected item
         //return somevalue; 
      },{timeout:120000});
    //listen to console events in the chrome tab and log it in nodejs process
    page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Cheerio (este empecé a verlo hace un rato):
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

```
const init = async () => {
    const $ = await request({
        uri: 'https://www.lcfc.com/matches/results',
        transform: body => cheerio.load(body)
    });
    const matchContainer = $('.match-item__team-container');
    console.log(matchContainer.html());
};

init();
```

Les comento que el primer ejemplo me devuelve este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el segundo me devuelve **null** en la consola. Alguna sugerencia? No es necesario que sea de los dos, solo que de uno pueda obtener información de forma correcta, de ahí creo que voy a entender como seguir solo.
Gracias!

Comment: Te sugiero utilizar `cheerio` y `axios` para hacer **web scrapping** pues estos dos en conjunto son bestias para ello!, `axios` creo que te servira para obtener la pagina mediante una peticion, mientras que `cheerio` te permite hacer como tal el scrapping, para que puedas obtener mejores ejemplos de esto encontre este video hace unos meses que me parecio super interesante: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htI9ddAhDVQ en ese video se explica muy bien como usar `axios` en conjunto con `cheerio` para aquello que necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el contenido de la página se esta generando dinámicamente en el cliente.

Probá poner "Ver código fuente" y ver si lo que estás buscando está en el HTML inicial de la respuesta.

En el caso de que se genere dinámicamente tenés que usar algo como `JSDOM`, `Selenium` o embeber tu programa en `Electron` para cargar la página como lo hace un navegador